# Skip Error Messages When Opening Workbook EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

When I open a spreadsheet I always get the 2 error messages below one after the other.

Is there any VBA I can use to just skip these messages so they do not display on open ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your spreadsheet has remote data sources. Fix or remove them.

Answer (score 0):

If this is coming from your own VBA then

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Comment: its wasn't from VBA, i didn't think i had any links to another workbook, but somehow a named range i was using was linking to a workbook that no longer existed